# Converting Latin characters to quoted-printable in python

Tags: python, quoted-printable

How to convert Latin characters to `quoted-printable` encoding in Python?

I know about [quopri](https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html) but it doesn't work with Latin characters (maybe I'm doing something wrong).

Here is my code:

```py
import quopri

fly_as_quoted_printable = b'=28=46=6C=79=29'
fly_as_bytes = quopri.decodestring(fly_as_quoted_printable)
fly_as_utf8 = fly_as_bytes.decode('utf-8')

print('\nСonverting `quoted_printable` to bytes and string is ok:')
print(f'fly_as_quoted_printable= {fly_as_quoted_printable}')
print(f'fly_as_bytes= {fly_as_bytes}')
print(f'fly_as_utf8= {fly_as_utf8}')

cyrillic_and_latin_mixed_as_bytes = bytes('Полёт (Fly)', 'utf-8')
quoted_printable = quopri.encodestring(cyrillic_and_latin_mixed_as_bytes)

print('\nBut converting latin characters as bytes to `quoted_printable` does not work:')
print(f'cyrillic_and_latin_mixed_as_bytes= {cyrillic_and_latin_mixed_as_bytes}')
print(f'quotep_printable= {quoted_printable}')
```

The output is:

```
Сonverting `quoted_printable` to bytes and string is ok:
fly_as_quoted_printable= b'=28=46=6C=79=29'
fly_as_bytes= b'(Fly)'
fly_as_utf8= (Fly)

But converting latin characters as bytes to `quoted_printable` does not work:
cyrillic_and_latin_mixed_as_bytes= b'\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x91\xd1\x82 (Fly)'
quotep_printable= b'=D0=9F=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=91=D1=82 (Fly)'
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?  `quopri.decodestring('=D0=9F=D0=BE=D0=BB=D1=91=D1=82 (Fly)').decode()` correctly returns `'Полёт (Fly)'` doesn't it? The " (Fly)" part was already printable.

Comment: @wim Yes, `(Fly)` is printable, but in my VCF files the Latin characters are encoded as `quoted-printable`, and I'm afraid that the contacts will not be added correctly to the phonebook if I leave them unencoded.

Comment: All normally printable characters are represented as themselves in quoted printable. It’s not some format where every character is converted to byte representation

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen In that case I don't understand why when exporting contacts from the phone all Latin characters are converted to quoted-printable. Thanks, I'll try to test importing contacts to the phone without encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stdlib `quopri` module does not bother to quote byte ordinals which don't need to be quoted ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e6a9cbd1147a67d9128f5fa3e82f8f0ee77dee93/Lib/quopri.py#L21-L34)).

To also encode already printable characters, you could escape them manually, but it's probably not necessary. For "(Fly)" that would be like:

```
>>> ''.join([f"={ord(c):X}" for c in "(Fly)"])
'=28=46=6C=79=29'
>>> quopri.decodestring(''.join([f"={ord(c):X}" for c in "(Fly)"]))
b'(Fly)'
```